# How to update entities in a namespace in Datastore

Tags: python-3.x, replace, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a namespace called "items" with a bunch of propertis in it. One property is called "incidentLocation" and one is called "incidentState".

For anywhere where "incidentLocation" is null, I want to copy the value for "incidentState" over to it. Then, I want to remove the "incidentState" property.

I am using the python client for Datastore. How can I retrieve and update each entity in a given namespace?

Edit:
I figured out how to retrieve the entities

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client(project="myproject")
query = client.query(kind='spots', namespace='items')

print(list(query.fetch(10)))
```

Still not sure how to update each entity back into the db though

Answer (score 0):

[GQL](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference) does not support updates.  Cloud Datastore is not a relational database, it's a document database, so instead of thinking about columns, you should think about the entire document.  In this case, it looks like you should consider running a [Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) job over your `items` kind to add the new `incidentLocation` property.

To write your entities back to your database you should use [put](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/client.html#google.cloud.datastore.client.Client.put).  You should look at using [batches](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/batches.html) to reduce the number of RPCs you send, that should give you better throughput.

Comment: I'm using the python client now, hoping to pull and update each entity in the database. but `items` is a namespace, and not a kind. having learned more, I think I'll update this question to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.